# If I dup a file descriptor can I make one side blocking and one non-blocking

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

I have opened a socket via `connect` and want to be able to read results blocking and write non-blocking.  My current solution is to set the file descriptor to be non-blocking and then `select` when I do a `read`.

It would be simpler instead to do something like

```
int sock = socket(...);
connect(sock, ...);
int reader = dup(sock);
int writer = sock;
fcntl(writer, F_SETFL, fcntl(writer, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Does the call to `fcntl` cause both `reader` and `writer` to be non blocking (it sets it on the I/O object) or does `fcntl` set non-blocking on the file descriptor?

Comment: If you use `select`, why set it to non-blocking? What's the purpose of having it non-blocking for the sake of writing to it?

Comment: You can verify this yourself by doing `F_GETFL` on both fd's and compare the return values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the `fcntl` man page carefully, you see the status flags are associated with a **file description**, not a file descript**or**.  And `dup` says the new and old file descript**or** refer to the same file descript**ion**.  So accesses to `reader` and `writer` should both be non-blocking.